# Compare arrays in matlab by elements

Tags: arrays, matlab, compare, equality

I want to compare multiple arrays in MATLAB element-by-element; and if they equal at any position, increment the count. (i.e whole array need not be equal, whenever the comparison finds the elements equal for the FIRST time that is enough. Ex `A=[1 2 3]`, `B=[4 2 5]`, here at position `2` its equal.)

I tried `isequal(A,B)`: that compares all the elements and returns Count `1` or `0`;
but `isequal(A[i], B[i]);` does not work to compare numbers as element by element.

Can you suggest any solution please..

Comment: do you mean: `find(A==B, 1, 'first')`?

Comment: Can you give an example with three arrays? How do you have those multiple arrays? Are they rows of matrix?

Comment: Ex: A=[1 2 9] B=[4 5 9] C=[7 8 9]; here all arrays are of same length and at index 3 they are equal. they are rows

Comment: @jagan: ok if you had multiple arrays, concatenate them as matrix rows, and use: `find(all(diff([A;B;C])==0), 1, 'first')` (similar to what LuisMendo showed below). This will return the index `3`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if(sum(A == B))
    % increment your counter
end;
```

EDIT:

Why it works: (A == B) returns a new array, with ones on pleces at wchich A and B have the same values, and zeros otherwise. "Sum" sums over this new array, and if this sum is non-zero (i.e. A and B have at least one common value at the same place), "if" is triggered. Otherwise sum returns zero, which is treated by if statement as "false".

Answer (score 0):

use a for loop using an index counter that goes through the index of an array one by one and compare the elements of the arrays one by one.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I'm not sure what you want. I assume that, given a set of row vectors with the same number of columns, you want to know at *how many* columns *all* those vectors have the same value (but the value can be different for each column).

I also assume your data is in the form of rows of a matrix, for example

```
 data = [ 1 2 9 3 5
          4 5 9 3 5 
          7 8 9 2 5 ];
```

Then:

```
result = sum(all(diff(data)==0));
```

In this case the result is `2`, because the equality condition is satisfied at *two* columns (third and fifth).

---

If you want to find the index of the *first* column where *at least two* rows have equal values:

```
 result = find(any(diff(sort(data))==0),1);
```

For example,

```
data = [ 1 8 9 3 5
         4 5 9 3 5 
         7 8 9 2 5 ];
```

would give `2`, because the second column is the first that has equal values.

Comment: Thank you for the reply; My question: I have 3 arrays, all of same length. As you mentioned in your example here at index 3 (value 9) they are equal so set result=1, that is sufficient. but NOT to find 'sum' (how many times equal values are there throughout the array). I need to find how early i find a comparision becomes equal.

Comment: @jagan So you want the first column in which all vectors have the same value?

Comment: Sir:Luis Mendo:Need not be so. any two values are equal in a coloumn, then its fine.That is when we look at a coloumn if there are multiple (2 or more) entries for a same number, then it must return that coloumn index .  Thanks

Comment: @jagan Return only the first column where that happens? Or all columns where that happens?

Comment: 2 Luis Mendo:yes, first coloum where it finds a match : it must return the index of that coloumn.

Comment: Luis Mendo:yes, first coloum where it finds a match : it must return the index of that coloumn.   Though it is not my requirement now- interested to know how to do if it has to return all coloumns where it  finds a match( i think: s=circshift(A,[Row 0]); here i shift matrix A's row ('Row' number of times) and then use: d = bsxfun(@eq,s,A) to check it has any match or not..)

Comment: @jagan To find all such columns, not just the first: remove `,1` in my last line. That is: `result = find(any(diff(sort(data))==0));`

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3 arrays that are all the same size (A, B, and C), and you just wanted to know where your equalities are, you could use:

```
R(:,:,1) = bsxfun(@eq,A,B);
R(:,:,2) = bsxfun(@eq,C,B);
R(:,:,3) = bsxfun(@eq,A,C);
IDX = find(R);
[Rows,Columns,~] = ind2sub(size(R),IDX);
```

and that will give you two vectors containing the row and column locations of all of your equalities. I tried this using the arrays:

```
A = [4 6 2 4
     3 5 4 4];
B = [6 2 6 3 
     2 1 4 4];
C = [4 4 4 2
     4 5 6 1];
```

and got

```
Rows = [2 2 1 2]
Columns = [3 4 1 2]
```

which do correlate to the locations of the various equalities. If you want to find the first location, just run:

```
CL = min(Columns);
RW = min(Rows(Columns == CL));
```

and that will give you the row-column index of the first equality. In the above example, it gives `RW = 1, CL = 1`